# OpenXDK Questions

Tags: xbox

I was strolling around XBox development. Apart form buying a DevKit from Microsoft, another thing got my attention is called, OpenXDK which stands for Open XBox Development Kit.

From their [main site](http://openxdk.maturion.de/) its pretty obvious that there hasn't been any update since 2005 but digging a little deeper, I found that in their project repository  is was being updated. *Last time stamp was 2009-02-15.* Quick google search said, its not actually really on a good place to poke around. Many and MANY features are absent. Being a hobby project I perfectly understand. But, those search results/posts/comments are quite old.

The question is, is there anybody who has any experience with OpenXDK? If is, that is it possible to shade some light on this? about its limitations? Is this a mature project? How's the latest version and what's it capable of doing?

Or should I just stay away from it?

Comment: It's not obvious from the site whether they're talking about Xbox or Xbox 360. And why not just use XNA?

Comment: According to the GPU and CPU specs in the website, it's the original Xbox. The Xbox was phased out very quickly when Xbox 360 came out, which explains the lack of updates.

Comment: Last time stamp in their sourceforge repository is 2009-02-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project itself is very outdated, it lacks many many many components that are in the actual XDK, aside from that fact, its for the original Xbox.. In my opinion just stay away from it, you're much better off sticking to personal computers, if you would like to do console development your best chances are to go to XNA (I hate to say it because I hate C#) or applying to work at a developer that does work on Xbox 360.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, Would you please elaborate on " many many many components"?

Comment: The official XDK has:
-A detailed documentation for advanced graphics and CPU control.
-Advanced audio libraries.
-Multiplayer/Session/Xbox Live/Networking libraries.
-Testing/Automation/Certification Tools.
-Xbox User Interface libraries and design tools.
-System tools such as Guide access, Game Disk Caching, Kernel debugging, Threading, CPU caches, Performance tuning, File I/O, Intrinsic math libraries, OpenMP, Encryption tools, and many more features..